# Database modeling: Inheritance

Tags: mysql, sql, database, model, eloquent

I cannot quite figure out how to model my database with this Problem:

> - A **journey** has one **driver**.
> - A **journey** has multiple **passengers**.
> - Both **driver** and **passengers** are **users**.
> - A **user** obviously can have multiple **journeys**, where he is either a **driver** or **passenger**.

I thought about a pivot table `journey_role_user`, but that wouldn't really work.
I am developing this with Laravel's Eloquent, not that that would change any of the relations.

Comment: If each journey only ever has one driver, then put `driver_id` on the `journey` table and have a `journey_passenger` table that links passengers to each journey.

Answer (score 0):

Four tables:

```
Journey:
journey_id
other_info

User:
user_id
other_info

Journey_Passenger:
journey_id
user_id

Journey_driver:
journey_id
user_id
```

You can also add a `driver_id` column to the `Journey` table to avoid the `Journey_Driver` table

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following five tables:

```
journey (id PK, name, driver_id)
users (id PK, name, ...)
roles (id PK, name, ...)
user_roles (user_id, role_id)
user_journeys (user_id, journey_id)
```

There are 3 base tables here, `journey`, `users`, and `roles`.  The `journey` table stores metadata for each journey, including the driver.  For this, it stores a `driver_id`, which would be a foreign key pointing to an `id` in the `users` table (since a driver must be some user).  The `users` and `roles` tables store metadata about each user and each role.

There are two junction/bridge tables here, `user_roles` and `user_journeys`.  The `user_roles` table stores the roles which a user might have.  It is possible of course for a user to be both a driver and a passenger, in which case that user might have *two* entires in the `user_roles` table.  The `user_journeys` table stores the user roster for each journey.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend three tables:

```
users:
    user_id,
    . . .

journey:
    journey_id,
    driver_id references users.user_id
    . . .

journey_passenger
    journey_passenger_id,
    journey_id references journey.journey_id,
    passenger_id references user.user_id,
    . . .
```

"driver" and "passenger" just seem to be roles that users can have.  These can be defined by the referencing table.